# How to download and save in filemanager or download folder pdf file and videos with React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

i want to download pdf and videos in react native app.But still i'm facing problems.Please give me the solution code for that.

Comment: have you tried react-native-fs ?

Comment: **yes** i have tried